# If Let Error - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[NSObject : AnyObject]'

Tags: swift

Here is my code.

```
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(email, password: password) { (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            PushNotication.parsePushUserAssign()
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Welcome back, \(user[PF_USER_FULLNAME])!")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            if let info = error.userInfo {
                ProgressHUD.showError(info["error"] as! String)
            }
        }
    }
```

This causes error like "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[NSObject : AnyObject]'"
Is there anybody who knows solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error.userInfo` is not an Optional, it's of type `[NSObject : AnyObject]` as hinted by the compiler. No need to unwrap it with `if let`, it will never be `nil`.

You can replace

```
if let info = error.userInfo {
    ProgressHUD.showError(info["error"] as! String)
}
```

with

```
ProgressHUD.showError(error.userInfo["error"] as! String)
```

if you're *sure* the value will be a String.

Otherwise, the dictionary value should be safely unwrapped and downcast as a String. Example:

```
if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {
    ProgressHUD.showError(errorString)
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with examples and more details (the first version of my answer was a bit light indeed, sorry about that).

Answer (score -2):

Please update code to this:

```
ProgressHUD.showError(error.userInfo["error"] as! String)
```

Then it will work.